# Ajax request related to different files placed in different folders

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a folder named `html`

```
 html/index.php
 html/jquery/primary.js
 html/ajax/request.php
```

`Index.php` file is in html folder and `primary.js` in the sub folder `jquery` Now I have made an ajax request from `primary.js` file like this

```
$.post('../ajax/request.php',{id:"//some id"},function(result){
     // some statments                      
});
```

But here the ajax request is incomplete. It says `file not found`. I was thinking primary.js is in jQuery folder so I used `../ajax/` to go back one directory and jump to `ajax` but it does not seem to work; surprisingly, when I moved the file to `html/request.php` and made ajax request simply `request.php` it worked. And when I used `../request.php` (since `primary.js` is in another directory `jquery` I made one step back and directed to file but it does not work.

What I have understood is no matter where you do the ajax request, the ajax request file must be within the directory of `index.php` and should be used in ajax request like this `request.php` no matter where the `primary.js` file is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path for your `$.post` is relative to the URL you are currently on because your javascript file is loaded and executed from there.

If you are in index.php you are in the **/html/** folder so the url to your ajax request should be `ajax/request.php` instead.